# NSURLComponents componentsWithString - Rule

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I'm writing unit tests to test out a URL generator class.

I'm using `NSURLComponents componentsWithString]` to generate the final URL object.

Is there a rule regarding how `componentsWithString` escapes forward slashes (/)?

**Case 1:**

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString: @"/foo"];
urlComponents.scheme = @"http";
urlComponents.host = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.bar.com"];
// [urlComponents URL] = http://www.bar.com/foo - Seems okay
```

**Case 2:**

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString: @"////foo"];
urlComponents.scheme = @"http";
urlComponents.host = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.bar.com"];
// [urlComponents URL] = http://www.bar.com//foo
```

**Case 3:**

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString: @"//////foo"];
urlComponents.scheme = @"http";
urlComponents.host = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.bar.com"];
// [urlComponents URL] = http://www.bar.com////foo
```

Why do Case 2 and 3 reduce the number of slashes to 2 and 4 respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Your case 2 and 3 don't conform to RFC 3986 path format as specified in the NSURLComponents documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents?language=objc

> The NSURLComponents class is a class that is designed to parse URLs based on RFC 3986 and to construct URLs from their constituent parts.

From the path section: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3 of the RFC 3986 spec it mentions that your path can't begin with `//` unless there's an authority component:

> If a URI
> does not contain an authority component, then the path cannot begin
> with two slash characters ("//").

If you adjusts your case 2 and 3 to have at least one character in between like this:

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString: @"/a/////foo"];
```

I believe it should output the correct number of slashes.